# Reg.exe Error: Too many command-line parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I have a command in my bat file that appends the Path environmental variable:

```
reg.exe ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"
```

However, I get an error: "Error: Too many command-line parameters"

How can I successfully append without using the GUI?

Comment: I'd bet, `%PATH%` contains spaces. Put quotes around it: `"%PATH%"`

Comment: `SETX.EXE` is the Windows built in command to change system variables etc.

Comment: @foxidrive: be cautious using `setx`.  It sometimes hangs.

Comment: @harryjohnston Thanks, it may be fixed.  The reports on google first page show posts from 2002 to 2007 and a couple in 2010. https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=setx+hangs

Comment: @foxidrive: nope, seen here just a few weeks back.

Answer (score 0):

the code

```
reg.exe ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"
```

Should read like this

```
reg.exe ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%PATH%";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"
```

If the path was all one like like this `C:\windows\system32` then it would work with out editing. But if it has spaces like `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Intel Corporation\` then as it has a space then cmd read's it as `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Intel` so you will get your error.

Comment: I get "ERROR: Invalid syntax".  Removing the quote marks either side of the semicolon fixes the problem.